# Proving that if $X_n$ is uniformly bounded, and if $X = \lim_{n}X_n$ with probability 1, then $E[X] = \lim_{n} E[X_n]$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

In Billingsley's Probability and Measure Book, he has a result otherwise known as the Bounded Convergence Theorem:

[image]

Normally we would use the Lebesgue integral in lieu of the expectation and also use the almost everywhere condition. However, he uses convergence in probability instead. What confuses me is how he is able to put a bound on $\mid X \mid$. Is that a deterministic bound or is it under the assumption that:

$$
P(\mid X \mid \leq K) = 1
$$

Thanks.

Comment: Because $X=lim_n X_n$ a.s., $X$ is bounded a.s., i.e. $P(|X|\leq K)=1$.

Comment: I think I remember a result in analysis saying that if a sequence is convergence it is bounded. If true, not sure if it applies

Comment: @Danielsen Is this result from the following? We know that $X_n$ being bounded means that $-K \leq X_n \leq K$ implies that $-K \leq lim_{n \to \infty}X_n \leq K$ implies that $-K \leq X \leq K$? I know this holds for sequences, but am not sure if this holds for functions as in this case. Also, if I have that $P(\mid X \mid \leq K)=1$, does that mean I can take it to be valid and truth? Thanks!

Comment: @user136503 $X=\lim_n X_n$ a.s. means exist a set $\Omega^*\subset\Omega$ with $P(\Omega^*)=1$, such that for every $\omega\in\Omega^*$ $X(\omega)=\lim_n X_n(\omega)$. So $-K\leq X(\omega)\leq K$ for every $\omega\in\Omega^*$. Then we have $P(|X|\leq K)=1$.

Comment: @Danielsen Hi, sorry to keep asking, I am still learning analysis -- when you go from $X(\omega) = \lim_{n}X_{n}(\omega)$ to $-K \leq X(\omega) \leq K$, was that just by taking limits across the inequalities like what I did or is is there perhaps a deeper proof behind it? Thank you.

Comment: @user136503 By fixing $\omega$, it is just the limit of sequence of numbers.

Comment: @Danielsen Got it, if I may ask just one more thing, do you know where I can find a proof of the fact above that if $P(\mid X \mid \leq K) = 1$, then $\mid X \mid \leq K$?

Comment: @user136503 $P(|X|\leq K)=1$ and $|X|\leq K$ a.s. are the same thing. You can not get $|X(\omega)|\leq K$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: @Danielsen Ah, that totally helps me see where I got it wrong -- I think I had thought the above inequality for $\mid X_n(\omega)-X(\omega) \mid$ in proof of the book held for all $\omega \in \Omega$ instead of just on a set of probability 1 -- so no wonder you had talked about $P(\mid X \mid \leq K) = 1$, thanks so much!!!!

Comment: @Danielsen Hi, sorry, I just saw above that he says that the bound on $\mid X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)\mid$ holds for "all \omega". In this case, why did you choose to work with a bounding result that holds almost surely?

Comment: @user136503 $X=\lim_n X_n$ a.s., the limit not convergence for every $\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: @Danielsen It seems to me that if $\mid X(\omega) \mid \leq K$ doesn't hold for all $\omega$, then $\mid X-X_n \mid \leq 2K$ doesn't hold for all $\omega$ as well. Therefore, does the book make a mistake by saying that $\mid X(\omega) - X_n(\omega) \mid \leq 2KI_{A}(\omega) + \epsilon$ for ALL $\omega$?

Comment: @user136503 More accurately say for almost all $\omega$, some times "a.s." was omitted.